# Disable Focus - AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, focus

I'm relatively new to Flash, and I was just wondering if there was any way to keep the focus off certain elements (specifically, a button, but also input text areas and such alike).

It's nothing to drastic, but it annoys me having the tab key focus on a button rather than other things. I'd rather just be able to disable the focus on that object permanently if that possible.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable that your component (object) get the focus when the <kbd>**Tab**</kbd> key is pressed, you can use the [`tabEnabled`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#tabEnabled) property and set it to `false`, like this :

```
// button control
var button:Button = new Button();   //  fl.controls.Button
    button.tabEnabled= false;
addChild(button);

// input text field
var text_field:TextField = new TextField();
    text_field.type = 'input';
    text_field.tabEnabled = false;
addChild(text_field);
```

Also, for a [`UIComponent`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/core/UIComponent.html) like [`fl.controls.ColorPicker`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/ColorPicker.html), [`fl.controls.ComboBox`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/ComboBox.html), ..., you can use the [`focusEnabled`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/core/UIComponent.html#focusEnabled) property like this :

```
// color picker control
var color_picker:ColorPicker = new ColorPicker();   //  fl.controls.ColorPicker
    color_picker.focusEnabled = false;
addChild(color_picker);

// slider control
var slider:Slider = new Slider();   //  fl.controls.Slider
    slider.focusEnabled = false;
addChild(slider);
```

Hope that can help.